# How to calculated the the completion percentage by using the formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have created the below fields.
Total Task - number field
Completed Task - number field

Completion Percentage = ?  Formula field.

How to calculate the completion percentage and show up in the above formula field. I am new in salesforce. Please help.

e.g:

Total Task - 10
Completed Task - 2

Completion Percentage = what is the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Completed Task/Total Task ) * 100
```

Or you can define a percent result type in your formula here:

[image]

Then the calc is just:

```
(Completed Task/Total Task )
```